# How to "cat" a socket?

Tags: cat, echo, socket, netcat

So to read and write to a socket:

Write to a socket:

```
echo "hello" > /dev/tcp/192.168.0.144/27002
```

Read from socket:

```
netcat -p 27002 -l
```

---

BUT... I would like to read a socket using "cat" and not have to use something else like netcat: ?

```
cat /dev/tcp/192.168.0.144/27002
```

ERROR:

```
cat: /dev/tcp/192.168.0.144/27002: No such file or directory
```

Tried and hangs:

```
cat < /dev/tcp/192.168.0.144/27002
```

How to use "cat" to read from a socket or port?

Comment: That `/dev/tcp/host/port` paths are a feature of your bash shell, they're not real files provided by your OS. You can only use them with redirections, so `cat </dev/tcp/192.168.0.144/27002`

Comment: The aptly-named `socat` comes to mind. Before I think about preparing an answer, could you help me verify correctness by adding some things to the question? I'm after: what is the underlying motivation? How are you creating the socket (assuming it exists before you try echoing to it)? Can we assume that the expected output is "hello"?

Comment: cat < /dev/tcp/192.168.0.144/27003 __
bash: connect: Connection refused __
bash: /dev/tcp/192.168.0.144/27003: Connection refused

Comment: Of course, if you don't have anything listening on that port

Comment: `netcat -l -p port` does not *read* from that socket, but *listens* on that port, accepts a connection, and then either *writes* or *reads* from that connection. If you run `echo yes | netcat -l -p 27003` in a window, then `cat </dev/tcp/localhost/27003` in another will print `yes`. If you're wondering if you can do what netcat does using just bash redirections, the answer is no, you can't.

Comment: Sockets are not a "file-like" abstraction, so you cannot `cat` from them. In particular, you need a "listen" action. As has been mentioned in the comments, use `socat`, `netcat` or a similar program.

Comment: Nitpicking: you can use cat with input redirected from the socket, once the connection is established as a client. The socket is bidirectional. What can't be done with bash is to wait for an incoming connection. In theory waiting like this would work with UDP from a single remote peer (which will have to bind the source port), except the "listening" port will be chosen randomly by the system, because it wasn't bound first, so the remote peer needs side channel information to transmit data to the right port.